# status 500 internal server error on ajax post - Laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

i try to make a post data with ajax post, but when i sent data with this, i have got error 500 internal server error

i have done adding csrf token, but still error, this is my  ajax code

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    headers: {
    'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
    },
    url: "{{ route('touchpoint.add') }}",
    data: {
        content_id: "15",
        content_type: "clip",
        actual_position: e.position,},
    // dataType: 'json',
    dataType : 'json',
    success: function (json) {
        console.log('success');
    }
});
```

and this is my controller

```
if (!$request->ajax()) {
            return "";
        }

        if (!empty(session('user'))) {
            echo "login dulu";
        }

        $params = [
            'content_id' => $request->content_id,
            'content_type' => $request->content_type,
            'actual_position' => $request->actual_position,
        ];

        $response = $this->apiPostReward('/touchpoints', $this->getTokenRewards(), $params);

        if ($response->status->code == 0) {
            $return = [
                'status' => 0,
                'message' => 'Success adding point'
            ];
            return response()->json($return);
        }
        else {
            dd($response);
        }
```

I can't find any bug, so I assume I am doing something incorrectly.

Comment: "*I have got error 500 internal server error*" - Check your logs (`storage/logs/laravel.log`); all 500 errors are logged there.

Comment: Try to use `dd()` to find line which has problem

Comment: @SerhiiPosternak `dd()` doesn't help much in an AJAX or API request; `dd()` is treated oddly by them, as it's echoing out HTML instead of returning a `response()`. On that note, @syehbiherbian, consider adding a valid response if `response->status->code` doesn't equal 0, like `return response()->json($alternateReturn, 500);`, etc.